# angular - event of a directive handled by parent controler

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

everyone ! I've this on my directive template...

```
    <div class="priceSlider" ui-slider="slider.options" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" 
step="0.01" use-decimals ng-model="sliderVal"><div>{{currency}} {{sliderVal[0]}} - 
{{currency}}     {{sliderVal[1]}}</div>
```

..and I've this on my JS for the directive

```
angular
.module('app.directives.categoryHead', [])
.directive('categoryHead', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        controller: function($scope){
        $scope.sliderVal = [$scope.min , $scope.max];
        $scope.slider = {
            'options': {
                range: true,
                start: function (event, ui) { console.log('Event: Slider start - set with slider options', event); },
                stop: function (event, ui) { console.log('Event: Slider stop - set with slider options', event); }
            }
        }
        },
        scope: {
            language : "=",
            currency : "=",
            breadcrumb : "=",
            min : "=",
            max : "="
        },
        templateUrl: "templates/directives/categoryHead.html"
    }
```

});

...and on my route template, I've this...

```
 <category-head breadcrumb="breadCrumb" min="categoryList.minPrice" 
max="categoryList.maxPrice" language="webshop.language" 
currency="webshop.culture.currency"></category-head>
```

So, basically I've a slider...that's fires the events starts and stop - And this works really fine.
But I'd like to handle the event not inside the directive, but on the controller of the route template.

How can I "transfer" the event from the directive to the template controller ? I just need to fire a "something changed" and send a notification of the new values.

ty !

Answer (score 0):

There are probably lots of different ways to do this. One option is to make your directive take event handlers that you have defined in your controller, like this:

`<your-directive on-start="startHandler()" on-stop="stopHandler()></your-directive>`

Then, in your directive config:

`scope: {
  onStart: '&',
  onStop: '&'
}`

Then, add something like this to your start/stop methods within the directive.

`$scope.slider = {
  'options': {
    range: true,
    start: function (event, ui) { if (onStart) onStart(event); /* other stuff */ },
    stop: function (event, ui) { if (onStop) onStop(event); /* other stuff */ }
  }
}`